# How to make CanDeactivate work with kendo-ui angular dialog

Tags: angular, rxjs, kendo-ui, modal-dialog, candeactivate

I'm trying to implement this [CanDeactivate Route Guard](https://www.developer.com/languages/javascript/preventing-data-loss-in-angular-applications-using-a-candeactivate-route-guard/) using kendo-ui angular dialog instead of the window.confirm,

It works fine with window.confirm but with kendo-ui dialog only the second time I execute the dialog. The first time the method `this.confirmCanExitDialog()` returns false even if I click Yes and the second time I execute the dialog by trying to navigate somewhere else, it returns true.

The problem I have is that this line `return this._canExitResult$$.value;` executes before the dialog.result even if I make the method return an `Observable<boolean>`, the result is always false (initial value). Please help.

[image: kendo-ui dialog]

```
 public canExit(): boolean {
    return this.form.dirty ? this.confirmCanExitDialog() : true;
  }

 private confirmCanExitDialog(): boolean {
    const dialogRef = this.dialogService.open({
      content: ConfirmDialogComponent,
    });
    const confirmDialog = dialogRef.content.instance as ConfirmDialogComponent;
    confirmDialog.message = 'Confirmation.CanExit';

    dialogRef.result.subscribe((result: DialogCloseResult) => {
      if (result === 'Yes') {
        this._canExitResult$$.next(true);
      }
      if (result === 'No') {
        this._canExitResult$$.next(false);
      }
    });
    return this._canExitResult$$.value;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.confirm` is a blocking call and this is why this code works:

```
 public canExit(): boolean {
    return this.form.dirty ? window.confirm() : true;
 }
```

If you want to use non-blocking dialog like kendo, then you have to return `Observable`/`Promise`:

```
canDeactivate(component: any, currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, currentState: RouterStateSnapshot, nextState: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    return this.form.dirty ? this.confirmCanExitDialog() : of(true);
}


private confirmCanExitDialog(): Observable<boolean> {
    const dialogRef = this.dialogService.open({
      content: ConfirmDialogComponent,
    });
    const confirmDialog = dialogRef.content.instance as ConfirmDialogComponent;
    confirmDialog.message = 'Confirmation.CanExit';

    return dialogRef.result.pipe(map(x => x === 'Yes'));
  }
```